# Non-resolvable parent POM for org.glassfish.javaeetutorial:dukes-tutoring

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, glassfish, java-ee-7

i want to setup duke tutoring project in netbeans.for that i had following

configurations-jdk8,netbeans 8.0.2,glassfish 4.1,apache-maven-3.3.3

i don't have duke tutoring project in my glassfish directory tut-install/examples/case-studies so i downloaded java_ee_sdk-7u2.zip and after extracting i copied that duke tutoring project and import that project in netbeans with file->open project->

but when i go to build and run the project i got following errors

```
[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
Non-resolvable parent POM for org.glassfish.javaeetutorial:dukes-tutoring:[unknown-version]: Failure to find org.glassfish.javaeetutorial:case-studies:pom:7.0.5 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 13
 @ 
The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]

  The project org.glassfish.javaeetutorial:dukes-tutoring:[unknown-version] (/home/yogesh/Downloads/dukes-tutoring/pom.xml) has 1 error
    Non-resolvable parent POM for org.glassfish.javaeetutorial:dukes-tutoring:[unknown-version]: Failure to find org.glassfish.javaeetutorial:case-studies:pom:7.0.5 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 13 -> [Help 2]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

my pom structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>case-studies</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.javaeetutorial</groupId>
        <version>7.0.5</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.javaeetutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>dukes-tutoring</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>dukes-tutoring</name>
    <modules>
        <module>dukes-tutoring-common</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                    <executable>${glassfish.home}/bin/asadmin${glassfish.executables.suffix}</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>    
        </plugins>      
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I can give you some hints maybe it would be helpful.

First, you need the project to be in the folder it's located by default otherwise you need to make many changes to the POM file since a lot of configurations are referenced into the parent POM file such as glassfish home folder and version and many other things. like this line:

`<executable>${glassfish.home}/bin/asadmin${glassfish.executables.suffix}</executable>`

Second, open the project as it is mentioned (because the project has dependencies in 2 modules) "open Project dialog box, navigate to: tut-install/examples/case-studies Select the dukes-tutoring folder. **Select the Open Required Projects check box and click Open Project.**" ...

Third, build the project (dukes-tutoring) with its dependencies. if you are using netbeans you can right-click on the project and click "build with dependencies"

Four, after building successfully run the glassfish server and use `mvn install` to deploy the project(dukes-tutoring).

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the parent project also.

Inside **java_ee_sdk-7u2.zip** in the folder `glassfish4\docs\javaee-tutorial` you have to extract the complete **examples** folder somewhere. Then open the **dukes-tutoring** project inside this folder.

For more information read [The Java EE Tutorial - Running the Duke's Tutoring Case Study Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/dukes-tutoring004.htm)

Comment: i  copied complete examples folder somewhere. Then i open the dukes-tutoring project inside this folder by open project wizard but it still gives error --------------Non-resolvable parent POM for org.glassfish.javaeetutorial:case-studies:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact org.glassfish.javaeetutorial:javaeetutorial:pom:7.0.5 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 13
 @

Comment: is i have to create any schema for this project

Comment: i also tried with procedures  To Build and Deploy Duke's Tutoring Using Maven by going to tut-install/examples/case-studies/dukes-tutoring/ by using terminal and i started server by asadmin and server up and running and after that maven install then build successfully but 404 error while accessing http://localhost:8080/dukes-tutoring-war/

Comment: i had given my all procedures please resolve my problem,its getting very difficult to understand the problem to me

Comment: now this errors after running through commad line ------ Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (create-tutoring-realm) on project dukes-tutoring-war: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "/home/yogesh/glassfish4/bin/asadmin" (in directory "/home/yogesh/Music/glassfish4/docs/javaee-tutorial/examples/case-studies/dukes-tutoring/dukes-tutoring-war"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]